# Fast indexing using multiple ES nodes?

Tags: java, indexing, elasticsearch, lucene, scalability

All I read and understand about running multiple ES nodes is to enable index replication and scaling. I was wondering if it could help us to make indexing faster for large number of files. I have two questions and they are as follows:

Question 1: **Would it be accurate to think that using multiple ES nodes would allow us to index multiple times faster?**

Question 2: **what effect does it have on indexing if I keep enable all nodes as a data node? on the other hand what effect does it have on indexing if I have few non-data nodes (e.g. one dedicate Master and one dedicate Client node) with few data nodes? Which will be better in terms of speed and scaling?**

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/blog/performance-considerations-elasticsearch-indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer1:** No.

The speed of indexing will in fact decrease if you enable replication (though it may increase search performance). You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896332/how-to-optimize-indexation-on-elasticsearch/29896977#29896977) for improving indexing performance.

**Answer2**: It depends (if no replica then same).

During indexing the data will go only to data nodes. Your cluster state will contain information about which nodes is data node and route the request accordingly. The performance impact will only be because of the node receiving the request has to reroute/forward the request to the data nodes

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding machines without increasing the number of replicas you will get a better performance during indexing. It is not surprising since you are adding more resources while the amount of work to be done remains pretty much the same.

In our environment we are using 20 nodes on production and 5-10 nodes on debug. Both environments hold the same volume of data. Since ES updates speed (We are using groovy scripts to merge new documents to existing documents) is our primary bottleneck, we are able to see much better performance in our production environment in oppose to other environments.

You already got some useful links at other answers to your question. I can add that in our case the 3 most significant factors in data upload improvements were: Reducing the refresh_interval, increasing the merge_factor and using Elastic-Hadoop plugin (We upload the data from Spark) that handles all the major data transfer optimisation on the application level.

- Every one of those steps have its own disadvantages, so read the manuals carefully before changing the configurations.